# Decrease the sensitivity of rotation of arrow (React native + PanResponder)

Tags: react-native, math, canvas, rotation, panresponder

Does anyone know how can I decrease the rotating velocity of arrow which is below.
I'm using panResponder and have some simple maths to rotate the arrow image.

The rotation is too sensitive, its is working fine for me but some how I'm not able to decrease the velocity

Code Link:
https://snack.expo.dev/bLVo169CM

Video:
[image]

Thanks in advance ✨

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but changing the divisor maybe ?
Like so :

```
          let x0 = x.current + 100 / 4;
          let y0 = y.current + 100 / 4;
```

Comment: Did this also but some time come back to its position after 2 or 3 rotation